# What is multicast?

Tags: java, tcp, multicast

I'm reading Ignite documentation and now I'm at the section about [Clustering](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-config#multicast-based-discovery). Here is specified that

> **Multicast Based Discovery**
>
> `TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder` uses Multicast
>   to discover other nodes in the grid

I dont understand that uses Multicast, what does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Multicast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast) is a way of transmitting information, you are maybe getting confuse with the term casting as a type cast from OOP, but in this context multicast is similar to broadcast communication, where a msg where information is addressed to a group of destination computers simultaneously.

That is how appache manages the sending of msgs in is group communication network

http://tomee.apache.org/multicast-discovery.html and the same applies to

https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/ignite.html

[image]

Broadcast would mean sending the msg to all the nodes in the network...(that is the main difference)

Comment: So is there a difference between mulitcast and broadcast?

Comment: @St.Antario yes, lots.  With appropriate network equipment in place a multicast transmission can cross subnet boundaries (depending on the "scope").  Also, devices have to explicitly subscribe to a multicast group in order to receive it, using IGMP.

Comment: @Alnitak So in case of broadcasting clients dont have to subscribe first to it. In case of multicast in turn each clients have to subscribe first in order to receive data. Is that correct?

Comment: @St.Antario more or less, yes.  IP multicast also uses a completely separate range of IP addresses (224.0.0.0 upwards) instead of using the link-local broadcast IP address (e.g. 192.168.1.255)